# How to get component instance in data section in vuejs template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that has complex rendering logic.
I try to carry out this logic to helper classes, for simplifying.
To do this, in the **data** section (for reactivity), I create class references as follows:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    state: new InitialState(this),
    query: new QueryController(this)
  })
}
```

As I understand it, at this point the context of `this` is not yet defined.
So, I have two questions.

1) Is there a way to pass the `this` component context in the **data** section (without lifecycle hooks)?

2) Is the approach with references to external classes of vuejs philosophy contrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it, at this point the context of `this` is not yet defined.

Only because of the way you've written the code. The component instance does exist and is available. It is sometimes used to access the values of props for determining the initial values of data properties.

For example, here is an example from the documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

```js
export default {
  props: ['initialCounter'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      counter: this.initialCounter
    }
  }
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you are using an arrow function. If you change it to the following then `this` will be available:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      state: new InitialState(this),
      query: new QueryController(this)
    }
  }
}
```

See also the note here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

> Note that if you use an arrow function with the `data` property, `this` won’t be the component’s instance, but you can still access the instance as the function’s first argument

As to your other question about whether using classes like this is contrary to Vue...

I don't think the use of classes like this is encouraged but they can be made to work so long as you understand the limitations. If you have a clear understanding of how Vue reactivity works, especially the rewriting of properties, then it is possible to write classes like this and for them to work fine. The key is to ensure that any properties you want to be reactive are exposed as properties of the object so Vue can rewrite them.

If you don't need reactivity on these objects then don't put them in `data`. You'd be better off just creating properties within the `created` hook instead so the reactivity system doesn't waste time trying to add reactivity to them. So long as they are properties of the instance they will still be accessible in your templates, there's nothing special about using `data` from that perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Component instance is already available when `data` function runs, this is one of reasons why it has been forced to be a function.

Due to how lexical `this` works with arrow functions, it's incorrect to use them to access dynamic `this`. It should be:

```
  data() {
    return {
      state: new InitialState(this),
      query: new QueryController(this)
    };
  })
```

The problem with `InitialState(this)` is that the entire component instance is passed instead of relevant data, this breaks [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Despite Vue isn't focused on OOP, there's nothing wrong with using classes. One of possible pitfalls is that classes may not play well with Vue reactivity because it puts restrictions on the implementation. Another pitfall is that classes cannot be serialized to JSON and back without additional measures, this introduces limitations to how application state can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I think computed is a better way to do what you want

```
export default {
    computed:{
        state(){
            return new InitialState(this);
        },
        query(){
            return new QueryController(this);
        }
    }
}
```